# How to print out the contents of a LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, iterator, linkedhashmap

Here is my code,

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project8Q3 extends President {

    private static LinkedHashMap<String, President> presidents;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String selection = null;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            presidents = new LinkedHashMap<String, President>();

            addPresident("16", "Lincoln", "Abraham", null);
            //a few more president's info but you get the idea

            System.out.println("******************************************");
            System.out.println("* G - Get a president's information      *");
            System.out.println("* D - display all president's information*");
            System.out.println("* X - Exit the  program                  *");
            System.out.println("******************************************");
            System.out.println("Enter your selection: ");

            selection = in.next();

            if (selection.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("G")) {
                System.out.println("Enter the president's ID: ");
                showPresident(in.next());
            } else if (selection.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
                showPresidents();
            } else if (selection.equalsIgnoreCase("X")) {
                System.out.println("\nThank you for using the PRESIDENT DATABASE. Good-bye!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("INVALID SELECTION! TRY AGAIN!\n");
            }
        } while (!selection.equalsIgnoreCase("X"));
        in.close();
    }

    public static void addPresident(String id, String lastName,
            String firstName, String middleInitial) {
        President president = new President(id, lastName, firstName, middleInitial);
        presidents.put(president.id, president);
    }

    public static void showPresidents() {
        //presidents = new LinkedHashMap<String, President>();

    }

    private static void showPresident(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

I am trying to print out the president's information, in the "showPresidents()" function. (clearly). I'm taking too many programming language course right now and I think I'm confused about how to print out the LinkedHashMap. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: what java version do you use?

Comment: So you want to print the entire map?

Comment: Yes, I would like to print out the entire map, and I use version 8 (update 161) does that answer your question @NikolayShevchenko

Answer (score 4):

To print a particular `President` given the name, you need to access the `presidents` map using the name as the key, and print out the value. To print out all presidents, we can loop over keys in the `presidents` map as follows:

```
public static void showPresidents() {
    for (String key : presidents.keySet()) {
        showPresident(key);
    }
}

private static void showPresident(String string) {
    System.out.println(presidents.get(string));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, kindly. Anyway I could have made my question better? I feel like I had too much code.

Comment: I think your question was clear -- posting all of the code gives more context and helps us answer your question. Maybe you could have posted what you've already tried, otherwise it seems like you're just asking us to do your homework for you, rather than an honest request for help.

Comment: I will do that in the future, thank you. I see how you could say that. I looked up all kinds of similar questions. The trouble is when writing my code I'm confusing python and java so I thought it wouldn't be helpful.

Comment: Note!!! This code works perfectly with the program IF you fix my code for selection = 'G' or 'g' it needs to use in.next() instead of in.nextLine()

Answer (score 3):

The recommended way to do so is using an iterator over the map:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, President> entry : presidents.entrySet()) {
    President president = entry.getValue();
    String name = entry.getKey();
    //Do something
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Define toString method for your class

```
class President {
    .....

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "President{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", lastName=" + lastName +
                ", firstName=" + firstName +
                ", middleInitial=" + middleInitial +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And then just call

**Java 8 and higher:**

```
presidents.forEach((id, president) -> System.out.println(president));
```

**Java 7 and lower:**

```
for (President p : presidents.values()) {
    System.out.println(p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call toString:

```
System.out.println(presidents.toString());
```

Note that this will call toString on the `President` object and give you `com.package.President@123abc` when printed (the part after `@` varies by the instance). If you want to print the content of the president you can either override toString in President:

```
@Override public String toString(){
    return some formatted version of your object
}
```

Alternatively, you could of course iterate over the map and print it like that:

```
for(Entry<String, President> entry : presidents.entrySet()){
    String key = entry.getKey();
    President value = entry.getValue();
}
```